# sql select query to get count of posts, followers and following for specific user

Tags: sql, select, mariadb

I have one database named `sdb`, In it there are 3 tables `users`, `posts` and `users_follow`

create table queries for all 3 tables are following

```
-- users table

CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `user_status` enum('active','inactive','remove') DEFAULT 'active',
 `signup_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[users table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJcj.png)

```
-- posts table

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `content` text NOT NULL,
 `posted_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
 KEY `posts_fk1` (`user_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `posts_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[posts table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54EEC.png)

```
-- users_follow table

CREATE TABLE `users_follow` (
 `follow_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `follower_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `following_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `follow_status` enum('active','blocked') DEFAULT 'active',
 PRIMARY KEY (`follow_id`),
 KEY `users_follow_fk1` (`follower_id`),
 KEY `users_follow_fk2` (`following_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_follow_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `users_follow_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`following_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[users_follow table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjkRN.png)

I try following query (for user with user_id = 1)

```
SELECT a.user_id,
   SUM(CASE WHEN f.following_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_followers,
   SUM(CASE WHEN f.follower_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_followings,
   SUM(CASE WHEN p.user_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_posts
FROM users_follow f
RIGHT JOIN users a
ON f.following_id = a.user_id
RIGHT JOIN users b
ON f.follower_id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN posts p
ON p.user_id = a.user_id
where a.user_id = 1;
```

above query return same count for `count_posts` and `count_followers`, `count_following = 0`

**output:** [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhfFa.jpg)

Comment: and the question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you probably need something along these lines

```
select a.user_id,
       (
          select count(*)
          from posts p
          where a.user_id = p.user_id
       ) count_posts,
       (
          select count(*)
          from users_follow f
          where f.follower_id = a.user_id
       ) count_followings,
       (
          select count(*)
          from users_follow f
          where f.following_id = a.user_id
       ) count_followers
from users a
```

If you would like to write it using `GROUP BY` and outer join than you definitely need to make it inline subqueries. Therefore something like this

```
select a.user_id,
       p.count_posts,
       f1.count_followings,
       f2.count_followers
from users a
left join (
  select a.user_id, count(*)
  from posts p
  group by a.user_id
) p on p.user_id = a.user_id
left join 
(
      select f.follower_id, count(*) count_followings
      from users_follow f
      group by  f.follower_id
) f2
left join f2.follower_id = a.user_id
(
      select f.following_id, count(*) count_followers
      from users_follow f
      group by  f.following_id
) f2 on f2.following_id = a.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the `user_follow` table can be improved:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_follow` (
 -- get rid of `follow_id`
 `follower_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `following_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `follow_status` enum('active','blocked') DEFAULT 'active',
 PRIMARY KEY (follower_id, following_id),
 KEY `users_follow_fk2` (`following_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_follow_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `users_follow_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`following_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 left join to do that like below:

```
    SELECT USERS.ID,
        COUNT(POSTS.ID) AS POSTS_COUNT,
        COUNT(FOLLOWINGS.FOLLOWING_ID) AS FOLLOWINGS_COUNT,
        COUNT(FOLLOWERS.FOLLOWER_ID) AS FOLLOWERS_COUNT
    FROM "Users" AS USERS
    LEFT JOIN "Posts" AS POSTS ON POSTS.USER_ID = USERS.ID
    LEFT JOIN "Followers_followings" AS FOLLOWINGS ON FOLLOWINGS.FOLLOWER_ID = USERS.ID
    LEFT JOIN "Followers_followings" AS FOLLOWERS ON FOLLOWERS.FOLLOWING_ID = USERS.ID
    WHERE USERS.ID = 2
    GROUP BY USERS.ID,
        POSTS.USER_ID
```

Comment: Recommend explaining how the null values from the left joins won't be counted in the Count() aggregations.